# Eclipse go directly to line number using resource with line

Tags: java, eclipse

When looking at external (tomcat) log,

Can I go directly to specific line number using exception message

Without/skipping using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

E.g. Exception is at `My.java:105`

Enter My:105 or My.java:105  and get directly to line 105?

Such shortcut exists in Intellij as [Navigate to file](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000134664-Navigate-to-File-and-Method-or-Line-Number-in-One-Command):

> "Navigate | File..." supports line numbers (e.g. "file:23" -- will go to line 23 in the file

Can this be consider as a valid Eclipse enhancement if not exists?

Comment: Try : `Ctrl` + `L`

Comment: @NicholasK updated, I want direct link as intellij

Comment: Have you tried holding down Ctrl/Cmd and clicking?

Comment: @nitind is it  useful for getting text from log

Comment: @nitind it is less useful when getting text from external log

Comment: Enhancement requests should be made in Bugzilla, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/, rather than here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Copy `My.java:105` to the clipboard and hit **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>** ([***Open from Clipboard***](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-09/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-menu-navigate.htm)).
  Alternatively, first hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then enter `My.java:105` or `My:105` (if the clipboard content does not match a pattern, a dialog opens to enter something).
- When using **[AnyEdit Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/anyedit-tools)** put the cursor somewhere to `My.java` and hit **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>** (***Open File under Cursor***)

Comment: Thank you for another great answer